# Access Classes Object Data from ActiveRecord callback to external Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two classes, both make API calls to the same server using an OAuth 2 Bearer Access token. I'm trying to wrap the API related code up in a module so that I can utilize ActiveRecord's callback functionality from both these classes easily.
I cannot find anywhere that describes how to access the calling class's data (or if I have to pass it as a parameter with the callback).

```
module M
  BASE_URL = 'www.googleapis.com'
  TOKEN = *generated oauth token*
  module N
    def my_method
      print("id: #{C.id}")
      print("fname: #{C.f_name}")
      print("lname: #{C.l_name}")
      print("address: #{C.address}")
    end
  end
  module O
    def my_method
      #assume this does something different from module N
      print("id: #{D.id}")
      print("fname: #{D.f_name}")
      print("lname: #{D.l_name}")
      print("address: #{D.address}")
    end
  end
end

class C
    include M
    attr_accessible :id, :f_name, :l_name, :address
    after_create N::my_method
end
class D
  include M
  attr_accessible :id, :f_name, :l_name, :address
  after_create O::my_method
end
```

How would I go about accessing the class C's data from within module M's my_method? Or am I completely off base?

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? If you include `M` in `C` then `C` instances can call `my_method` and have access to their own attributes. I don't know if I understand the question

Comment: I get a 'NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for M:Module):'
More specifically, I have a module nested within another module that is included in the class

Comment: JFYI, ruby community standard for indentation is two spaces.

Comment: If @SergioTulentsev 's answer doesn't help you then you might want to update your question with more code examples, being as specific as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including `ModuleA` in `ClassB` gives `ClassB` all of `ModuleA`'s instance methods as if they had been defined directly in `ClassB`. The methods are no different than any of `ClassB`'s other instance methods. You call them the same way (`b = ClassB.new; b.a_method`), and within the method `self` will be the instance of `ClassB` that's calling the method, so you have direct access to any other methods or variables defined within the `ClassB` instance scope.

If you have a nested Module you can include it in its parent, and then any Class that includes the parent will have access to the nested Module's methods.

```
module A
  module B
    def where_am_i
      "Inside mod B"
    end
  end

  include B
end

class C
  include A
end

c = C.new
c.where_am_i # => "Inside mod B"
```

In your case the two nested Modules should have different definitions of the same method name, so you want to include only one or the other. You do so with the syntax `include ParentModule::NestedModule`

```
module M
  BASE_URL = 'www.googleapis.com'
  TOKEN = *generated oauth token*

  module N
    def my_method
      print("id: #{id}")
      print("fname: #{f_name}")
      print("lname: #{l_name}")
      print("address: #{address}")
    end
  end

  module O
    def my_method
      #assume this does something different from module N
      print("id: #{id}")
      print("fname: #{f_name}")
      print("lname: #{l_name}")
      print("address: #{address}")
    end
  end
end

class C
  include M::N
  attr_accessible :id, :f_name, :l_name, :address
  after_create :my_method
end

class D
  include M::O
  attr_accessible :id, :f_name, :l_name, :address
  after_create :my_method
end
```

Comment: My problem was i was using a method called self.insert (which was limiting the scope to the module) I believe

Answer (score 0):

When you include it like that, then `self` in `my_method` will be an instance of C. And so you just access the attributes normally, as if it was a method in C itself.

```
module M
  def my_method
    print("id: #{id}")
    print("fname: #{f_name}")
    print("lname: #{l_name}")
    print("address: #{address}")
  end
end
```

Understanding the concept of "current `self`" and how different constructs (including a module, `instance_eval`, etc.) affect it, is crucial for becoming any good in ruby.

Comment: Does it matter then if the module method is nested inside of another module?
`module M
module N
  def my_method
    print("id: #{id}")
    print("fname: #{f_name}")
    print("lname: #{l_name}")
    print("address: #{address}")
  end
end
end`

Comment: @BryanGurney This piece of code is unreadable. But do try it.

Comment: @BryanGurney Then you have two choices: `include N` inside of `M`, and then `C` will have it as well (as will any class/module that includes `M`), or inside `C` you can `include M::N`

Comment: I believe this comment is what I was looking for.